# how to set an Excel sheet hidden with carbonfive ssTemplate API

Tags: java, excel, xsd

I use Carbon Five ssTemplate for generate an Excel file (xls). I have hidden sheet in my workbook but i cant hide them with this API. In the XSD we are a hidden attribut in the styleType element but i don't any have value of this attribute.

xml template :

```
<workbook bgcolor="#FFFFEE">

    <include template="../style.xml" />

    <style name="hiddenSheet" hidden="true" />

    <forEach var="jobContext" items="${setOfContext}">

        <sheet name="${jobContext.sheetName}" landscape="true" marginLeft="0.5" marginRight="0.5">
            <row>
                <cell style="label" colspan="3">${msg['label']}:</cell>
                <cell style="value" colspan="3">${data.value}</cell>
            </row>
        </sheet>

        <!-- Feuille cachée -->

        <sheet name="${jobContext.sheetName}_HIDDEN" landscape="true" marginLeft="0.5" marginRight="0.5" style="hiddenSheet">
            <row>
                <cell style="label" colspan="3">${msg['label']}:</cell>
                <cell style="value" colspan="3">${data.id}</cell>
            </row>
        </sheet>

    </forEach>
</workbook>
```

https://sstemplates.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sstemplates-core/src/main/resources/sstemplates.xsd

```
    <xsd:complexType name="SheetType">
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="style"    type="StyleType"/>
          <xsd:element name="row"      type="RowType"/>
          <xsd:element name="set"      type="SetType"/>
          <xsd:element name="if"       type="IfType"/>
          <xsd:element name="choose"   type="ChooseType"/>
          <xsd:element name="forEach"  type="ForEachType"/>
          <xsd:element name="while"    type="WhileType"/>
          <xsd:element name="include"  type="IncludeType"/>
          <xsd:element name="rowbreak" type="RowbreakType"/>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:attribute name="name"             type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="style"            type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="marginTop"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="marginBottom"     type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="marginLeft"       type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="marginRight"      type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="marginHeader"     type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="marginFooter"     type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="repeatRowFrom"    type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="repeatRowTo"      type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="repeatColumnFrom" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="repeatColumnTo"   type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="printRowFrom"     type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="printRowTo"       type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="printColumnFrom"  type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="printColumnTo"    type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="fitWidth"         type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="fitHeight"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="landscape"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="headerLeft"       type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="headerCenter"     type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="headerRight"      type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="footerLeft"       type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="footerCenter"     type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="footerRight"      type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="zoom"             type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="firstPageBreak"   type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="nextPageBreak"    type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
      </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="StyleType">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element name="row"      type="RowType"/>
      <xsd:element name="cell"     type="CellType"/>
      <xsd:element name="sheet"    type="SheetType"/>
      <xsd:element name="style"    type="StyleType"/>
      <xsd:element name="set"      type="SetType"/>
      <xsd:element name="if"       type="IfType"/>
      <xsd:element name="choose"   type="ChooseType"/>
      <xsd:element name="forEach"  type="ForEachType"/>
      <xsd:element name="while"    type="WhileType"/>
      <xsd:element name="include"  type="IncludeType"/>
      <xsd:element name="rowbreak" type="RowbreakType"/>
      <xsd:element name="function" type="FunctionType"/>
    </xsd:choice>
    <xsd:attribute name="name"              type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="align"             type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="borderBottom"      type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="borderTop"         type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="borderLeft"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="borderRight"       type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="border"            type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="bottomBorderColor" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="topBorderColor"    type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="leftBorderColor"   type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="rightBorderColor"  type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="borderColor"       type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="dataFormat"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="background"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="foreground"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="fillPattern"       type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="hidden"            type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="locked"            type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="wrapText"          type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="indention"         type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="rotation"          type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="valign"            type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="fontName"          type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="fontHeight"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="typeOffset"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="fontWeight"        type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="fontColor"         type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="underline"         type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="italic"            type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="strikeout"         type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="columnWidth"       type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="rowHeight"         type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="autoColumnWidth"   type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had no solution on the forum using Carbonfive ssTempalte's API, I implemented a workaround. I get the marshelled HSSFWorkbook object and parse the list of its sheets. If it contains the string _HIDDEN I put it in the list of hidden sheets of workbook.

```
public HSSFWorkbook build() {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        try {

            Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            context.put("msg", messageResources.getMessages());
            populateContext(context);

            SsTemplateProcessor processor = SsTemplateProcessor.getInstance();
            workbook = processor.process(new ClassPathResource(getTemplatePath()).getFile(), context);

            // For hide sheets
            if (needHideSheet) {
                int index = 0;
                while (index < workbook.getNumberOfSheets()) {
                    String sheetName = workbook.getSheetName(index);
                    if (StringUtils.contains(sheetName, "_HIDDEN")) {
                        workbook.setSheetHidden(index, true);
                    }
                    index++;
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error during marshalling of workbook template", e);
        }
        return workbook;
    }
```